# GET request with sockets returns corrupt data

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a problem with sockets. I make GET request with this code:

```
using (s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    s.Connect(host, 80);
    string requestS =
    "GET http://" + adress + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0\r\n" +
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
    "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n" +
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestS);
    Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[1000];
    s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
    int bytes = 0;

    do
    {
        bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
        page2 += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
        m.Write(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
    }
    while (bytes > 0);

}
```

And here is what i get from remote server:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 07 Mar 2015 10:02:48 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Pingback: http://www.example.com/blog/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://www.example.comhttp/www.example.com/somescript.php
Content-Length: 3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you see, location data is corrupted and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Well it looks like the problem is with `adress` or `host` - but we can't tell what those are, which makes it hard to help. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: what is the value of host and adress?

Comment: Additionally, is there any reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel here? What's wrong with `HttpClient` or `WebClient` or `WebRequest`?

Comment: Your `page2` code risks getting a multi-byte UTF-8 character split between two consecutive `Receive` calls, leading to it being decoded as two garbage characters.

Comment: Try UTF8 decoding outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything here that would cause this. The broken UTF-8 handling (as remarked in the comments) does not come into play for this bug because all chars here are ASCII.

The problem is somewhere else. Use Fiddler to make sure that the `Location` header is not being sent invalidly. Or, post executable repro code. Right now this is all that can be diagnosed.